# Creating JVM level and Thread Safe Sequence in DB

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sybase, sequences

It is old question but to be sure i am asking again.
Actually i have created sequence like in Oracle with a table and want to use with multiple threads and multiple JVM's all process will be hitting it parallel.

Following is sequence stored procedure just want to ask whether this will work with multiple JVM's and always provide unique number to threads in all jvm's or is there any slight chance of it returning same sequence number two more than one calls?

```
create table sequenceTable (id int)
insert into sequenceTable values (0)

create procedure mySequence 
AS
BEGIN
    declare @seqNum int
    declare @rowCount int

    select @rowCount = 0
    while(@rowCount = 0)
    begin
        select @seqNum = id from sequenceTable
        update sequenceTable set id = id + 1 where id = @seqNum
        select @rowCount = @@rowcount
        print 'numbers of rows update %1!', @rowCount
    end
    SELECT @seqNum
END
```

Comment: I don't think there is any synchronization in your procedure - that means your first `select` and `update` statements have a race - it's possible for concurrent select from another process to hit your table in-between select and update of another process, thus giving you two of the same values. (Your question is not related to Java, by the way).

Comment: Agree with @M.Prokhorov - this isn't strictly a Java question. Even so, why would you not simply use an actual sequence? Multithreaded Java apps have been using these for years

Comment: Because db doesn't provide sequence sybase and this stored procedure will be called by multiple JVM and threads. Also update will only work when Were condition will meet with same version of I'd otherwise it will add new value, I have tested it with 500 calls from Java unit test and each time it's giving different results which seems fine to me. I am asking to confirm may be some things hits.

Comment: M.Prokhorov  you are right it can have two values but then update will not work because of its where condition and loop will continue.

Comment: The use of the `while/select/update` construct looks like an 'optimistic locking' implementation, which should be sufficient for low volume calls to the proc; however, in a high-volume (proc) call environment you can end up with an excessive volume of passes through the loop while trying to generate a unique value; net result is that 'optimistic locking' is not recommended in an environment where you have a high volume of (concurrent) requests for key generation; I suggest you take a look at the answers (below) provided by Adam and me for solutions that can be used in a high volume environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose to maintain your current design of updating the `sequenceTable.id` column each time you want to generate a new sequence number, you need to make sure:

- the 'current' process gets an exclusive lock on the row containing the desired sequence number
- the 'current' process then updates the desired row and retrieves the newly updated value
- the 'current' process releases the exclusive lock

While the above can be implemented via a `begin tran` + `update` + `select` + `commit tran`, it's actually a bit easier with a single `update` statement, eg:

```
create procedure mySequence 
AS
begin
    declare @seqNum int

    update sequenceTable
    set    @seqNum = id + 1,
           id      = id + 1

    select @seqNum
end
```

The `update` statement is its own transaction so the update of the `id` column and the assignment of `@seqNum = id + 1` is performed under an exclusive lock within the `update`'s transaction.

---

Keep in mind that the exclusive lock will block other processes from obtaining a new id value; net result is that the generation of new id values will be single-threaded/sequential

While this is 'good' from the perspective of ensuring all processes obtain a unique value, it does mean this particular `update` statement becomes a bottleneck if you have multiple processes hitting the `update` concurrently.

In such a situation (high volume of concurrent `update`s) you could alleviate some contention by calling the stored proc less often; this could be accomplished by having the calling processes request a range of new id values (eg, pass `@increment` as input parameter to the proc, then instead of `id + 1` you use `id + @increment`), with the calling process then knowing it can use sequence numbers (`@seqNum-@increment+1`) to `@seqNum`.

---

Obviously (?) any process that uses a stored proc to generate 'next id' values only works if ***ALL*** processes a) always call the proc for a new id value and b) ***ALL*** processes only use the id value returned by the proc (eg, they don't generate their own id values).

If there's a possibility of applications not following this process (call proc to get new id value), you may want to consider pushing the creation of the unique id values out to the table where these id values are being inserted; in other words, modify the target table's id column to include the `identity` attribute; this eliminates the need for applications to call the stored proc (to generate a new id) and it (still) ensures a unique id is generated for each insert.

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate sequences in ASE. Use the `reserve_identity` function to achieve required type of activity:

```
create table sequenceTable (id bigint identity)
go

create procedure mySequence AS
begin
    select reserve_identity('sequenceTable', 1)
end
go
```

This solution is non-blocking and does generate minimal transaction log activity.

Comment: Will This guarantee it will not provide duplicate values even with multiple JVM?

Comment: You are using regular IDENTITY mechanism from the database. The database should guarantee you that. But remember - every identity needs its own table. If you want to use a second identity - you need to create a next table for it.

Comment: @user460293; notice that Adam's modified your `sequenceTable.id` column from `int` to `bigint identity`; while the use of `int` vs `bigint` is up  to you to decide, the `identity` attribute must be provided for the `reserve_identity(<table_name>,<number_of_ident_values_to_reserve>)` function to work properly

Comment: The details about this technique have presented at the ISUG-TECH 2015 by Rob Verschoor: https://www.slideshare.net/SAPTechnology/tips-tricks-and-little-known-features-in-sap-ase